# Scraping vs Google Trends API using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-trends

I'm trying to collect the top five search queries for each trend for the past year by category on Google Trends.

I don't know if I should do this using a python library such as `pytrends`, which from their docs require a keyword to be able to query GT, or I don't have any specific keyword, I want to fetch any search query for a term on every category that can be found.

Use a **scraping** library `Selenium` or `Beautifulsoup4` to collect this information directly from the [GT website](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=47&date=2019-01-01%202019-12-31).

The goal of this is to be able to retrieve the top 5 websites for each query later ...

Which direction should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use one of the unofficial APIs.

These connect to the Google internal APIs that power the Trends UI with structured information. But scraping would only return mostly unstructured HTML, and you would need to extract the structured data yourself. This information will not be as reliable or as complete.

It is the difference between talking through an API that is intended for "machine to machine" communication, vs a web UI that is intended for "machine to human" interactions.

Comment: I ended up using the unofficial APIs, thank you for taking the time and replying to this!

Comment: Great! I am glad you were able to make progress. Consider upvoting or accepting my answer if you think others will also find it useful.